# How to set Italic font on existing run without creating new XWPFRun run

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am attempting to apply italics to text within an XWPFRun run, but it is not working even though the element is set to  in XML.

```
for (XWPFTable tbl : doc.getTables()) {
                        for (XWPFTableRow row : tbl.getRows()) {
                            for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
                                for (XWPFParagraph p : cell.getParagraphs()) {
                                    for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
                                        String text = r.getText(0);
                                        if (text != null && text.contains(key) && key.equalsIgnoreCase("meter")) {
                                            r.setItalic(true);
                                            r.setText(text, 0);
                                        }
```

Comment: "but it is not working even though the element is set to in XML": What does that mean? Try debugging: `String text = r.getText(0); System.out.println(text);`: What text does it print? `r.setItalic(true);System.out.println(r.getCTR());`: What does it print? If both prints the expected, are you sure you write out the changed `XWPFDocument` to the correct file?

Comment: String tst = r.getText(0);
System.out.println("tst:" + tst); //tst:Calculator_GlucoseMeter
r.setItalic(true);
r.setText(text, 0);
CTR obj = r.getCTR();
System.out.println("CTR:" + obj); //
<xml-fragment>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
    <w:i w:val="true"/>
    <w:w w:val="90"/>
    <w:sz w:val="24"/>
    <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:t>Calculator_GlucoseMeter</w:t>
</xml-fragment>

Comment: Still, I am not getting italic fonts in a document.

Comment: The `<w:i w:val="true"/>` sets `i`talic formatting true. So it **should** work. Are you using an Apple system? Some Mac applications have a problem interpreting the `val` attributes correctly. Try `r.getCTR().getRPr().addNewI();` instead of `r.setItalic(true);`. That should set `<w:i />`.